# How do I check the number of affected rows on ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql, executenonquery

I am currently working on a C# project and I am running an insert query

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    SqlCommand GDR_EnumVoiePublique = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO GDR_EnumVoiePublique(VP_Id,VP_Nom,OVP_Id,LVP_Id,GVP_Id,Mun_Id,VP_Description)VALUES(@VP_Id,@VP_Nom,@OVP_Id,@LVP_Id,@GVP_Id,@Mun_Id,@VP_Description)", connection);

    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VP_Id", Guid.NewGuid());
    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VP_Nom", VP_Nom);
    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OVP_Id", OVP_Id == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : OVP_Id);
    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LVP_Id", LVP_Id == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : LVP_Id);
    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GVP_Id", GVP_Id == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : GVP_Id);
    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mun_Id", Mun_Id);
    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VP_Description", VP_Description);
    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //count = (Int32)GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Executescalar();
   //countResult = GDR_EnumVoiePublique.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Is there a way I can see how many rows were inserted during this query?

Comment: Use a counter top of your `while` statement?

Comment: the answer is in the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Well*, you can use a simple counter for that.

```
int counter = 0;
while(reader.Read())
{
   ...
   ...
   if(GDR_EnumVoiePublique.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
   {
      counter++;
   }
}
```

For `INSERT` statement, [`ExecuteNonQuery` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) returns the number of rows inserterd. That means; `GDR_EnumVoiePublique.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0` lines execute your INSERT query and if it is successful, returns `1`, if it is not, returns `0`.

Comment: it give exception 
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_GDR_ENUMVOIEPUBLIQUE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.GDR_EnumVoiePublique'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: This is no problem of the answer given by Soner, the problem is caused by your data. Debug it and check your values.

Comment: @JHDesigne It is clearly you try to insert a row with **same** primary key value which is not possible. Debug your code and check your values in watch debugger. I'm sure you will find some same values for your primary key column.,

Comment: but the PK is VP_Id and I insert always Guid.NewGuid()

 
and it worked for me befor I add the counter

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of inserted rows when `SET NOCOUNT OFF`.

```
Int affectedRows;

while (reader.Read())
{
    SqlCommand GDR_EnumVoiePublique = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO GDR_EnumVoiePublique(VP_Id,VP_Nom,OVP_Id,LVP_Id,GVP_Id,Mun_Id,VP_Description)VALUES(@VP_Id,@VP_Nom,@OVP_Id,@LVP_Id,@GVP_Id,@Mun_Id,@VP_Description)", connection);

    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VP_Id", Guid.NewGuid());
    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VP_Nom", VP_Nom);
    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OVP_Id", OVP_Id == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : OVP_Id);
    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LVP_Id", LVP_Id == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : LVP_Id);
    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GVP_Id", GVP_Id == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : GVP_Id);
    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mun_Id", Mun_Id);
    GDR_EnumVoiePublique.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VP_Description", VP_Description);

    affectedRows += GDR_EnumVoiePublique.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I already tried somthing like that but it give me an exception
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_GDR_ENUMVOIEPUBLIQUE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.GDR_EnumVoiePublique'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @JHDesigne: I think you are inserting the duplicate value in the table 'dbo.GDR_EnumVoiePublique' which has PRIMARY KEY constraint. So insert unique value into the table to avoid the error.

Comment: I deleted all content of the table so I don't think so

Comment: You are inserting the value to table in while loop, so there may be possibility to insert the duplicate value. Check it by debugging.

Comment: but the PK is VP_Id and I insert always Guid.NewGuid()